# Не отображается элемент в шаблоне laravel при @isset

Tags: php, laravel

После изменения пароля на сайте отправляю через контроллер переменную **pass_changed** которая равна **true**, в адресной строке браузера отображается *pass_changed=1* после изменения пароля.
Однако у меня не отображается информация на странице, что пароль изменён:

```
@isset($pass_changed)
    <div>Ваш пароль изменён</div>
@endisset
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
@isset(request('pass_changed'))
```

Comment: Попробовал, выводит ошибку: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead).
Попробовал @if($pass_changed !== null), выводит ошибку: Undefined variable $pass_changed

Comment: Спасибо, вариант с request('pass_changed') действительно помог

Answer (score 0):

Вот один из вариантов решения:

```
@if(request('pass_changed') == 1)
  <div>Ваш пароль изменён</div>
@endif
```